# Firebase Cloud Functions - Change Firestore settings

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Function and since recently, the logs show me this message:

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
>   not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
>   calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> ```
> const firestore = new Firestore();
> const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
> firestore.settings(settings);
> ```

The problem is that when I add that piece of code into my functions file, I get this error every time I try to deploy:

```
ReferenceError: Firestore is not defined
```

Can somebody help me find what could be wrong?

(Do I need to add a Firestore dependence in the package.json file? Even if I don't need to do it whereas I already use the Firestore features?)

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

// Add this magical line of code:
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```

Then in your function use the firestore object directly:

```
firestore.doc(`/mycollection/${id}`).set({ it: 'works' })
```

**UPDATE as of March, 2019**:

**If using `firebase-admin` version 7.0.0 or above, you no longer need this fix.**

In [Version 7.0.0 - January 31, 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node) of `firebase-admin` there were some [breaking changes](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v0.20.0) introduced:

> **BREAKING: The `timestampsInSnapshots` default has changed to true.**
>
> The `timestampsInSnapshots` setting is now enabled by default so timestamp
>   fields read from a `DocumentSnapshot` will be returned as `Timestamp` objects
>   instead of `Date`. Any code expecting to receive a `Date` object must be
>   updated.

What's more, as stated in [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Firestore#Firestore), `timestampsInSnapshots` is going to be removed in a future release so make sure to remove it altogether.

Comment: @Valentin glad to hear that. Happy coding :))

Comment: @Valentin please note that there are breaking changes after the release of version 7.0.0. I've updated my answer respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The advice you're getting in the logs is intended for people using the Firestore node SDK directly.  However, when you write Firestore triggers through Cloud Functions, the Admin SDK is initialized automatically, which in turn initializes the Firestore SDK automatically.  So, you don't have an opportunity to initialize it yourself.

Until the Firestore SDK is fully finalized, all you can do is make sure that your usage of dates is consistent with the future, fully released Firestore SDK.  This means you should use Timestamp objects when reading dates out of snapshots.  If you're doing that, you can ignore this warning message.

Comment: Hum. If I do this, I get this error: foo.dateTimeCreated.toDate is not a function

Comment: Would you mind asking a separate question with a complete, minimal code sample, along with whatever documents you're trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

Check how do you initialized your firebase app in my case I called it firebase so I use this:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */     timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);
```

Comment: This isn't going to work because Cloud Functions and the Admin SDK initialize the Firestore SDK directly (when working with Firestore triggers), and you don't have an opportunity to change the way that works.  Please see my answer here for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to do in Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';


admin.initializeApp();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
admin.firestore().settings(settings);
```

** The code above is written in typescript

Comment: Thanks Joel! This was helpful for Typescript :)